# Can I use where in Haskell to find function parameter given the function output?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, where-clause

This is my program:

```
modify :: Integer -> Integer
modify a = a + 100

x = x where modify(x) = 101
```

In ghci, this compiles successfully but when I try to print x the terminal gets stuck. Is it not possible to find input from function output in Haskell?

Comment: If something like this were possible, what do you think `f a = 3; x = x where f(x) = 5` would do? Or `x = x where sha256(x) = "44def5a6ed540de9718db47cb1fc086e148172e07637ecb41a160a5527334f85"`?

Comment: it would break cryptography 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = x where modify(x) = 101
```

is valid syntax but is equivalent to

```
x = x where f y = 101
```

where `x = x` is a recursive definition, which will get stuck in an infinite loop (or generate a `<<loop>>` exception), and `f y = 101` is a definition of a local function, completely unrelated to the `modify` function defined elsewhere.

If you turn on warnings you should get a message saying "warning: the local definition of `modify` shadows the outer binding", pointing at the issue.

Further, there is no way to invert a function like you'd like to do. First, the function might not be injective. Second, even if it were such, there is no easy way to invert an arbitrary function. We could try all the possible inputs but that would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: To make it even more drastic: it is also equivalent to `x = x where 325 = 433`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sure, but that's already hard for people to understand, and doesn't draw as clear a parallel as the simple renaming that chi used.

Comment: @amalloy right. In fact the version in the answer is not only equivalent to the one in the question, it is actually _identical_ up to α-renaming. My point was that this does not even matter, because you can put _any junk_ in a `where` block – as long as it's not concerned with the definition of an actually used variable/function, it is simply ignored.